# Finger elongates when rotating. Why and how do I fix it?

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm new to Blender and I've been following some hand rigging tutorials. However when I rotate the fingers they elongate. Why does this happen and how can I fix it so that they have more realistic movement. Please see screenshots below.

[image: after rotating]

[image: before rotating]

Comment: Hello, maybe try an Apply Scale (Ctrl A) in Object mode, if it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi Nick, i know you are new here...but...think of calling a car maintainer you tell him your car won't drive. Then you make a picture of your car. Won't help much right? Same with your question. We have no idea what you did, how your rig is configured and what settings you made. So i recommend providing your blend file so we can figure it out on our own. thx. By the way: you have already 2 close votes because of lack of detail so you should improve/edit your question.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for giving me your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have scaled your armature on an axis, you need to apply the scale in *Object* mode to prevent this kind of deformation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).